# Convert one column to date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert one column in a DataFrame to date format, but I don't know how to do it. The columns is FECHA_VENTA. This is the DataFrame:

```
df_tienda = pd.read_csv("VENTAS_LM.csv",sep=";")
df_tienda.dtypes
```

```
ID_CLIENTE_ISDI      int64
FECHA_VENTA         object
ID_TIENDA_ISDI       int64
ID_ARTICULO          int64
UNIDADES           float64
IMPORTE            float64
dtype: object
```

```
df_tienda.head()
```

```
    ID_CLIENTE_ISDI FECHA_VENTA         ID_TIENDA_ISDI  ID_ARTICULO UNIDADES    IMPORTE
0   506177785       06FEB2016:00:00:00  40              16545893    1.0         29.00
1   506636587       06FEB2016:00:00:00  18              14726026    1.0         1.95
2   505638060       06FEB2016:00:00:00  68              16723693    1.0         11.11
3   506636587       06FEB2016:00:00:00  18              17377241    1.0         6.40
4   506636587       06FEB2016:00:00:00  18              16326954    1.0         3.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Which dt format did you want? Examples below

```
df['FECHA_VENTA']= pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_VENTA'])

df_tienda.dtypes

df['FECHA_VENTA'] = df['FECHA_VENTA'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

df_tienda.dtypes

df['FECHA_VENTA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_VENTA'], format='%y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

df_tienda.dtypes
```